# How to Install Kaminari Properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, rubygems, kaminari

I'm having a bit problem on how to get Kaminari work. I did the installation procedure in GitHub.

```
gem "kaminari"
```

Then run

```
bundle
```

I have this snippet for index

```
@users = User.order("name")
```

I added this on my view

```
<%= paginate @users %>
```

Then I got this error.

```
undefined method `paginate' for #<#<Class:0x00000102934330>:0x00000102932508>
```

Did I missed something? I also tried to include the page method

```
@users = User.order("id").page(1)
```

But I get this error instead

```
undefined method `page' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x000001017d0300>
```

Comment: Did you remember to restart the server after running `bundle`?

Comment: also, remember to run the configuration generator.

Answer (score 4):

include **kaminari** and **bootstrap-kaminari-views** gems in your project Gemfile,

```
gem "kaminari"

gem "bootstrap-kaminari-views"
```

**Execute bundle install in terminal**,

```
$ bundle install
```

**In products_controller.rb**,

```
@products = Product.order("name")

@products = Kaminari.paginate_array(@products).page(params[:page]).per(5)
```

**In products/index.html.erb**,<%= paginate @products, :theme => 'twitter-bootstrap-3' %>

Answer (score 1):

take a look at the railscast for kaminari
 its really nice 
 http://railscasts.com/episodes/254-pagination-with-kaminari

**bash**
rails g kaminari:views default

**products_controller.rb**

```
@products = Product.order("name").page(params[:page]).per(5)
```

**products/index.html.erb**

```
<%= paginate @products %>
```

**app/views/kaminari/_prev_span.html.erb**

```
<span class="prev disabled"><%= raw(t 'views.pagination.previous') %></span>
```